# There are $2n+1$ real numbers having the property that the sum of any $n$ of them is less than the sum of remaining $n+1$.

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

There are $2n+1$ real numbers having the property that the sum of any $n$ of them is less than the sum of remaining $n+1$. Then,

a.) all the numbers must be positive

b.) all the numbers must be negative

c.) all the numbers must be equal

d.) Such a system of real numbers cannot exist

I don't know how to begin these type of questions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How can they all be positive and all be negative?

Comment: With $n=2$, the system $2,2,3,3,3$ tells you that $b,c,d$ are false. What lead me to this example? I just thought of maximizing the sum of the $n$ numbers I picked (so I pick the $n$ biggest numbers), and ensuring the rest are big enough so their sum exceeds this.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I believe that's a multiple choice question.

Comment: @PacoAdajar Yes you are right. Only one option is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1\geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_{2n+1}$ be the collection of numbers satisfying the property. Then, we have :
$$
a_{n+1}+...+a_{2n} + a_{2n+1} \geq a_1+a_2+...+a_n \geq a_{n+1}+...+a_{2n}
$$

(first follows from the premise, and the second from the ordering) and so $a_{2n+1} \geq 0$, but that's the smallest number.

---

Finally, $n=2$ and the collection $3,3,3,2,2$ refute the rest of the options.

---

As I mentioned earlier, the way to get this solution is to think in the extreme : although the condition "any $n$ numbers" sounds like a lot of conditions, it is the most stringent when you think of the largest numbers in the collection, because their sum can't exceed the sum of the rest . Now construct the example by considering small $n$, and trying to satisfy the conditions : the rest follows from ordering the numbers quite easily.

Comment: Thank you. I understood the answer.

Comment: You are welcome!